# Changes of Article.availableFrom in ShopWare has no effect

Tags: shopware

i opend the Shopware 5.4.6 backend and

set shop in **edit mode** (not productive mode). 
i Checked in `Settings > Performance` ✔ `Use shop in edit mode`

then i opend  `articel > overview > multichange`
and set **Article.availableFrom** for all products to
**2018-10-10 00:00:00**.

These changes of the Article.availableFrom I find over the following Select:

```
SELECT distinct available_from, changetime, datum FROM s_articles
2018-10-10 00:00:00, 2018-09-11 00:00:00, 2017-10-05
```

but the page reload (Shirt+F5) still shows:

`This article will be published on` **October 11, 2018**

That's why I tried the following (always followed by Themes compile and Web-page reload) in `Settings > Theme Manager`:

1. Compiler Caching deactivate OFF to ON
2. CSS komprimieren ON to OFF
3. JavaScript komprimieren ON to OFF

And *checked all* in `Settings > Performance > Cache` and pressed the button **Empty** (followed by then Web-page reload Shift+F5)

After all date i tried `Themes compile` and the i renamed the

then i renamed `/var/cache/production_201807181357` to
`/var/cache/backup_roduction_201807181357`
After that, SW has created a similar folder. My problem persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you are looking for is s_articles_details.releasedate. 
"availableFrom" is for the dropdown of the quantity.

Comment: works. I was surprised that the SQL update immediately changed also value in the web page. So without a recompile theme or something.